# How to get the address of ouput file from user in C#?

Tags: c#, file-io

I have a form which gets the some parameters from users and then output the results.  The problem is i like to get the desired name of output file from users. I have:

```
public void WriteKCore(string Address ?NameOfFile)
{
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Address + NameOfFile);
    for (int i = 0; i < node.Length; i++)
    {
        if (node[i].degree > 0)
        {
            Edge e = node[i].e;
            while (e != null)
            {
                if (e.nextNode.num > i)
                    sw.WriteLine(node[i].num.ToString() + " " + 
                    e.nextNode.num.ToString());
                e = e.nextEdge;
                //...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this function, i pass the preset location of the output file, but i like to give the name of file in a separate field. I get the *NameOfFile* by a textBox from user.

Comment: Why not use a [save file dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.savefiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: When combining multiple paths to get a full path you should you [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your code is not complete, providing basic usage of StreamWriter

```
public void WriteKCore(string path, string fileName, string content)
{
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(path, fileName), true))
    {
        writer.Write(content);
    }
}
```